# Check whether CDN is working or not

Tags: curl, cdn

Is there any way to find whether the static content is being served by CDN or not. Using curl, can i find whether the static file is being served by CDN or by the webserver.

Comment: this question really makes no sense.. a cdn should use a completely different hostname then your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your CDN provider there are several ways of direct / indirect test

- Cloudflare / AWS CloudFront will add additional headers when the request is served by them, you can inspect those to see if it includes headers indicating cache HIT / MISS.
- Tail your webserver logs while accessing your site, if you get hits directly on the server every-time you hit the url, there is probably no or misconfigured caching on your CDN.

Coming to some indirect measurement , I think these are more practical ways to see you are really getting any benefit from the CDN integration. 
Promise of CDN is reduced load times for your user all over the globe , how about measuring just that ? 
This lets you hit your server from locations spread across the globe and take measurement of various phases in HTTP request : https://is-it.online/

Following is test result for a URL which has CDN enabled , if you see regardless of where it was access it has almost similar load times , that is a definitive indicator at CDN is working for that site.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To test your setup, you can use a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) (or simply [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) from a client that is outside your network.